# terraform changes plan after modifying a variable that is not used

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a `env` variable where I define the different environments:

```
env = {
  "dev" = {
    "environment" = "development",
    "create_RDS"  = false,
    "db_password" = "postgres",
  },
  "int" = {
    "environment" = "integration",
    "create_RDS"  = false,
    "db_password" = "postgres"
  },
  "pre" = {
    "environment" = "staging",
    "create_RDS"  = true,
    "db_password" = "",
  },
  "pro" = {
    "environment" = "production",
    "create_RDS"  = true,
    "db_password" = ""
  }
}
```

Each name is bind to a terraform workspace (dev,int,pre,pro...)

Here is the creation of the database:

```
locals {
  vpc_id      = data.aws_vpc.this.id
  create_RDS  = var.env[terraform.workspace]["create_RDS"]
  db_password = var.env[terraform.workspace]["db_password"] != "" ? var.env[terraform.workspace]["db_password"] : random_password.db_password.result
  depends_on  = [random_password.db_password]
}

module "db" {
  source     = "terraform-aws-modules/rds/aws"
  version    = "~> 2.0"
  identifier = terraform.workspace

  count = local.create_RDS == true ? 1 : 0

  # Disable creation of RDS instance(s)
  create_db_instance = true


  engine               = "postgres"
  engine_version       = "11.10"
  family               = "postgres11"  
  instance_class       = "db.t3.micro"
  #instance_class       = var.env[terraform.workspace]["db_instance_class"]
  major_engine_version = "11"

  allocated_storage = 5
  storage_encrypted = true

  name     = "aqn${terraform.workspace}"
  username = "user_${terraform.workspace}"
  password = local.db_password
  port     = "5432"

  iam_database_authentication_enabled = false

  vpc_security_group_ids = [module.db_security_group.security_group_id]

  maintenance_window = "Mon:00:00-Mon:03:00"
  backup_window      = "03:00-06:00"

  # Enhanced Monitoring - see example for details on how to create the role
  # by yourself, in case you don't want to create it automatically
  monitoring_interval    = "0"
  monitoring_role_name   = "${terraform.workspace}-RDSMonitoringRole"
  create_monitoring_role = true

  tags = local.common_tags

  # DB subnet group
  subnet_ids = local.create_RDS ? data.aws_subnet_ids.private[0].ids : []

  # Database Deletion Protection
  deletion_protection = var.env[terraform.workspace].environment == "production" ? true : false
}
```

If I modify anything of the `env` variable, even in a different environment section, terraform tries to delete the database.

Just modifying "dev"  by adding "foo"

```
env = {
  "dev" = {
    "environment" = "development",
    "create_RDS"  = false,
    "db_password" = "postgres",
    "FOO"         = "BAR"
  },
  "int" = {
    "environment" = "integration",
    "create_RDS"  = false,
    "db_password" = "postgres"
  },
  "pre" = {
    "environment" = "staging",
    "create_RDS"  = true,
    "db_password" = "",
  },
  "pro" = {
    "environment" = "production",
    "create_RDS"  = true,
    "db_password" = ""
  }
}
```

When I `terraform plan` using `pre` workspace, terraform tries to delete the database

[Here](https://pastebin.com/u3xqpyiv) is the terraform plan output for the `pre` workspace after modifying a different environment variable.

¿Why terraform is deleting the database after adding a new map to a different environment?

Comment: Are you sure that you haven't changed anything else? Maybe you set create_RDS to false in pre as well? Can you double check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be related how terraform understand boolean variables in maps.

The boolean variable y have defined:

```
"pre" = {
    "environment" = "staging",
    "create_RDS"  = true,
    "db_password" = "",
    "foo"          = "bar"
  },
```

But then comparing the boolean variable "create_RDS" terraform interpret it's a string so I changed the expression (every boolean expression) to compare string instead of boolean and seems to work fine:

```
  subnet_ids              = local.create_RDS == "true" ? data.aws_subnet_ids.private[0].ids : data.aws_subnet_ids.private-pre.ids
```